# Blazor 6 webassembly openid reload page on siginresult

Tags: c#, blazor, openid-connect, webassembly, openiddict

I'm trying to adapt a sample (https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Weytta) from openiddict to work with a wasm client.

 I almost have it running but I'm struggeling with the last step.

What I have in the client (besides the default template code), nothing special:

```
In the startup
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "test_openid";
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";
    options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://localhost:44333/";    
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseMode = "query";
});
```

and added in the FetchData page

```
@attribute [Authorize]
```

And in the openiddict  sample made some small changes in the startup to match my client:

```
await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
            {
                ClientId = "test_openid",
                ConsentType = ConsentTypes.Implicit,
                DisplayName = "Test openid application",
                RedirectUris =
                {
                    new Uri("https://localhost:44390/authentication/login-callback"),                    
                },
                Permissions =
                {
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Logout,
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
                    Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
                    Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,
                    Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code, // New permission
                    Permissions.Scopes.Email,
                    Permissions.Scopes.Profile,
                    Permissions.Scopes.Roles,
                    Permissions.Prefixes.Scope + "demo_api"
                }
            });
```

So far the code, when testing I get good results in the flow

```
OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher: Information: The request address matched a server endpoint: Configuration.
OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher: Information: The configuration request was successfully extracted: {}.
OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher: Information: The configuration request was successfully validated.
OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher: Information: The response was successfully returned as a JSON document:
```

Also the in last step

```
OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher: Information: The request address matched a server endpoint: Token.
OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher: Information: The token request was successfully extracted: {
  "client_id": "test_openid",
  "code": "[redacted]",
  "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44390/authentication/login-callback",
  "code_verifier": "b61bc0c4c86f439eb8eb8691982682d3af9b51f5caf74f45be63c513d2b785d9553bf473a9b6432da2310db4c32a0f40",
  "grant_type": "authorization_code"
}.
OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher: Information: The token request was successfully validated.
```

But then, when I click on the FetchData page, my client does a complete reload and gives an (non) error in the page

```
There was an error trying to log you in: ''
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: In my case it was a missing userprofile endpoint configuration in `Startup.cs`:

`options.SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/oidc/user-info");`